# Extracting element from a bitarray using indexes in a list

Tags: python, numpy, bitarray

I got a list of index of element of a BitArray. I want to extract the elements.

If I try on this simple example the classical method

```
from bitstring import BitArray
barray = BitArray('0b101111011110101')
index = [1,2,3,4]
barray[index]
```

I got the error

```
IndexError: Slice index out of range.
```

It's the same if I use as index a tuple or a numpy array. I watched the documentation and the main funtion, it's weird for me, but it seems impossible and I don't know why.

It seems for that the only solutions is to do a loop, and I would like to avoid it for speed.

Anybody get an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to extract those as a NumPy boolean array -

```
np.take(barray,index)
```

Sample run -

```
In [156]: barray
Out[156]: BitArray('0b101111011110101')

In [157]: index
Out[157]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [158]: np.take(barray,index)
Out[158]: array([False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Ok on the principle, but I got a new problem : my file is too big for numpy.take (2Gb), I got a memory error